# To show that an entire function is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

[image]

For this problem, can I just simply apply Liouville's theorem?

Comment: I think you are thinking about $f(z)/(1 + |z|)^{1/2}$, but it asks for $f$.

Comment: Since z is a complex number, then the part $C(1+z)^{1/2}$ must be a constant. Therefore f is entire and bounded. It has to be a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$({1+|z|})^{1/2} $ is not bounded nor smooth at zero. So you can't apply liouvlles thrm.

Comment: Why do we need to show that?

Comment: Because this is why you get the contradiction. According to your reasoning, this function has to be entire, therefore constant, but it's not consrant. So what would be the problem?????

Comment: That's what I don't understand. How do you prove that is not a constant? by proving that it is not entire? How?

Comment: It's not constant because it gives different values. Let $z=0$ you get 1, let $z=3$ you get 2. So it's not constant.

Comment: But as long as it is a number, f is bounded. Isn't it?

Comment: No, as you see, as the number get bigger, the function increased. It's limit tends to infinity as $z $ goes to infinity.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: So you can not use liouvilles theorem, as the function on the right of the original inequality is not constant nor smooth. So the only way is obviously the one given in the solution. If you are satisfied with this answer please accept my hint above.